# Openbox is ignoring menu.xml

Tags: arch-linux, x11, openbox

I just set up openbox 3.6.1.

And pretty much what's going on is that no matter what I try to do with ~/.config/openbox/menu.xml or rc.xml, the right click menu will not change, it insists on being set to default. I tried configuring it with **obmenu**, according to obmenu everything is just fine. And of course I have tried **openbox --reconfigure**

[Here is the file in it's entirety](https://pastebin.com/duDcQAkH), it was autogenerated by **obmenu-generator**

I have not seen any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `openbox --reconfigure` to apply changes to menu.xml.

Look at this page on the arch wiki for more information: [Openbox reconfiguration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/openbox#Openbox_reconfiguration).

Comment: I know this, I did this, I went as far as restarting openbox, x11 and my computer, it still refuses to use the file.

Comment: That would be useful information in the question. Do you have something like `<menu>...<file>menu.xml</file>...</menu>` in your rc.xml?

Comment: Yes, it would seem that it is in there by default, and it is indeed set up that way.